# Differentiate between "Normal" Click and Click after Dragging

Tags: javascript, html, angular, draggable, dom-events

**Problem**

I have an image slider, and the issue is, that the click event on a preview image is fired after dragging.
I showcased it in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCbLHlMbksE&feature=youtu.be)

**Supposed Behavior**

The click event should only be triggered when the user did not drag beforehand.

**Code**

```
isGrabbing: boolean = false;
    startX: number;
    startXPerc: number;
    translateX: number = 0;
    diffPerc: number;

    @ViewChild('slider') slider;

    onMouseDown(e: MouseEvent): void {
        const pageX = e.pageX;
        this.isGrabbing = true;
        this.startX = pageX - this.slider.nativeElement.offsetLeft;
        this.startXPerc = this.translateX;
    }

    onMouseUp(e: MouseEvent): void {
        this.isGrabbing = false;
    }

    onMouseMove(pageX: number): void {
        if (!this.isGrabbing) return;
        const x = pageX - this.slider.nativeElement.offsetLeft;
        const diff = this.startX - x;
        this.diffPerc = 100 * diff / this.slider.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
        this.translateX = this.startXPerc - this.diffPerc;
    }

    get translateXValue(): string {
        return `translateX(${this.translateX}%)`
    }

    onSmallItemClick(i: number): void {
        // this line should only be triggered
        // if the user did not drag beforehand
        this.animate(i * -100);
    }
```

Html:

```
<div
    class="small-slider-container"
    (mousedown)="onMouseDown($event)"
    (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event)"
    (mouseup)="onMouseUp($event)"
    #slider
>
    <div
        class="small-slider"
        [style.transform]="smallTranslateXValue"
        [class.grabbing]="smallSliderGrabbing"
        [class.grab]="!smallSliderGrabbing"
    >
        <div
            class="item"
            *ngFor="let i of images; let j = index"
            [style.left]="j * 10 + '%'"
            (click)="onSmallItemClick(j)"
        >
            <div class="content">
                <img src="{{ i }}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*click* is triggered after *mouseup*. Your `onMouseUp` function needs to be combined with `onSmallItemClick`.

At the moment, *mousedown* happens and sets `isGrabbing` to true, then *mouseup* sets it to false. So, by the time *click* fires the user is 'not' grabbing.

From [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mouseevents-h3):

> The sequence of these events is:
>
> ```
> mousedown
> mouseup
> click
> ```

Comment: so I have to remove the click event and replace it with the mouseup event?

Comment: I've added the html, maybe this helps